# Searching for dimensional quantities

Tags: ebay

I find it extremely frustrating to try and find products on eBay which are **described with dimensional quantities**.

For instance: *looking for 3 1/2 inch long screws*.

Regardless how the length is described, the search results have a huge amount of 'noise' in them. It nearly makes the search useless.

For instance:

- 3 1/2
- 3 1/2"
- 3 1/2 in
- 3 1/2 inches
- 3.5
- 3.5"
- 3-1/2
- ad nauseum

etc.

I don't find that metric dimensions fare much better despite not having the confusing inch " symbol involved.

Narrowing down the categories helps somewhat but is usually totally insufficient.

Is there any reliable method of searching for this type of characteristic? Some way to get eBay to properly interpret the criteria as a dimension and not just a text description?